The marginal distribution and marginal density of e^x
I have the probability density
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-x}& \text{for $0\leq y\leq x$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$
Am i correct to assume that the marginal densities are $f_x(x)=xe^x \:\text{for $0\leq x \leq 1$}$ and $f_y(x)=e-1\:\text{for $0\leq y \leq 1$}$ and that the marginal densities are $F_x(x)=1+xe^x-e^x \:\text{for $0\leq x \leq 1$}$ and $F_y(y)=ye-y\:\text{for $0\leq y \leq 1$}$?
Furthermore, would this be a correct plot of the areas in R² where the density is positive? I have copied this sketch from the blackboard in class, but can not really make sense of what y=0 and x=0 refer to in this area.

The marginal $f_y$ cannot be right, it does not integrate to $1$.

That makes sense, but i can't see how to get it to that from e^x

$f_y(y)=\int_y^{1} f(x,y)dx$.

By definition, the marginal density of $X$ (assuming $x\ge 0$)
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) dy=\int_{0}^x f(x,y) dy=\int_{0}^x e^{-x} dy=xe^{-x}
$$
and
the marginal density of $Y$ (assuming $x\ge 0$)
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) dx=\int_{y}^{\infty} f(x,y) dxx=\int_{y}^{\infty} e^{-x} dx=e^{-y}.
$$
